# How to automatically start Tomcat after starting an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

We have an instance which needs to be turned on only during business hours. We have scheduled the times to start/stop the instances. The problem that I am facing is that, once the instance is started, we have to manually log into the instance and start Tomcat. I've tried to, start is as a service in Windows, with no luck. I tried to go about with User Data, but was not able to get my head around that...can anyone suggest a way in which I can automate starting Tomcat as well???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet (if you want to cut out a lot of trial and error) is probably to reinstall Tomcat with the .exe installer, and explicitly install it to run as a service.  (You could certainly accomplish this without reinstalling; I suggest reinstalling merely because when all's said and done, it'll will probably take you less time, unless you have lots of custom Tomcat config.)  Once it's installed as a service, go to Services and make sure the Tomcat service's "Startup Type" is "Automatic".  (You will probably be able to control the Tomcat service's Startup Type from the Apache Service Monitor in your system tray as well, without opening Services.)

Note that running Tomcat as a service may conflict with the way you schedule the starting/stopping Tomcat during business hours, but since it's not clear how you're doing that scheduling, I can't comment on it except to say that you should make sure, in your scheduler, that you're starting and stopping *the service*, not a windowed/console instance of Tomcat.  (Otherwise you could end up with either two Tomcats running on two different ports, or else errors from port conflicts.)